# Create 2 different mobile apps( Android + iOS, Android + iOS) with Xamarin having lot of common code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created an app for android( will create an iOS app later) in Xamarin in Visual Studio 2022.
I want to create another app with a lot of common code and screens.
What are the steps?

1. Create 2 different visual studio solutions 1 for each mobile app.
2. The shared code is converted into a DLL from 1 solution and referenced in another solution. I don't know how I will debug it in another solution.
3. Android and iOS common codes need to be duplicated.

Suggestions, please.

Comment: Referenced solution library (as opposed to referencing the resulting DLL) can be debugged just fine, though iOS debugging tends to have its own peculiarities when applying code changes on the fly.

Comment: Just a quick question but why are you creating a new xamarin app? Xamarin loses support in May of 2024. You should be creating a Maui app. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin#xamarin-releases

Comment: The xamarin.forms and the maui are cross-platform framework. You can just create one project.